# POST request Java CouchDB

Tags: java, http, couchdb

I have a couchdb on localhost:5984.
With Java I use this command to make a GET request:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Request {

    private String host = "";
    private int port = 80;
    private String path = "";
    private String method = "GET";
    private String body = "";
    private Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of HTTPClient
     */
    public Request() {
    }

    public void setHost(String host, int port, String path) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void addRequestHeader(String key, String value) {
        headers.put(key, value);
    }

    /**
     * returns 2 strings String[0] is the request String[1] is the response
     */
    public String[] send() throws IOException {

        String response = "";
        String request = "";

        // NETWORK STUFFS
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // crea la request
        request += method + " " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n";

        // aggiungi headers
        Enumeration keys = headers.keys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
            String value = (String) headers.get(key);
            request += key + ": " + value + "\r\n";
        }
        // controllo content-length, indispensabile per il POST
        if (headers.get("Content-Length:") == null) {
            request += "Content-Length: " + body.getBytes().length + "\r\n";
        }

        // linea di fine headers
        request += "\r\n";

        // aggiungo il body
        request += body;

        // invio
        //System.out.println(request+"\n");
        out.print(request);
        out.flush();

        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s + "\n";
            //System.out.println(s);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();

        String[] result = new String[2];
        result[0] = request;
        result[1] = response;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I insert: host, port and method type ("GET") and I use the send method in this class. All works fine.
Now I want to do a post request to send a JSONObject, what I have to do?
I already tried with same method adding a DataOutputStream, but I have a bad content type error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily) other StackOverflow question, you can have a basic example on how to post Data via HTTP with Java. In your case, you simply forgot to set the `'Content-type: application/json'` in your request.

Also, there are some Java libraries to let you query CouchDB in case you didn't know. Example : [ektorp](http://ektorp.org/)